# Deleting SQLite Database before opening a new database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-ndk

I'm having serious problems trying to get SQLite working with Android. I keep getting errors such as **"unknown error (code 14): Could not open database"**.

One method I found that gets rid of this error temporarily is to delete the database and then create one. There mightn't even be a database but calling deleteDatabase() seems to fix the problem.

```
File DB_PATH = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("test.db");
DB_PATH.mkdirs();

DatabaseHelper dbh = DatabaseHelper.getHelper(this);
SQLiteDatabase db;

SQLiteDatabase.deleteDatabase(DB_PATH);
db = dbh.getWritableDatabase();
```

**DatabaseHelper**

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context ctx) {
    super(ctx, ctx.getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("test.db").getPath(), null, 10);
    this.context = ctx;
}

public static synchronized DatabaseHelper getHelper(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    return instance;
}
```

What I'm wondering is why would deleting the database make a difference and any advice in general would be appreciated?

Comment: Could you post the code for DatabaseHelper? it is unclear what it does.

Comment: @Aegis sorry I forgot to include it. It's in now

Comment: First maybe try using SQLiteOpenHelper which handles creating and upgrading the database, also you don't have to specify a path for the database since it should always be created inside the application directory.  The methods getWritableDatabase() and getReadableDatabase will automatically create a database for you if it does not exist.

Comment: @Aegis I'm using the NDK and SQLite Android Bindings https://www.sqlite.org/android/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki so you have to specify the whole path

Comment: why are you using SQLite Android Bindings? is it for encryption?

Comment: BTW could this because of `In Android, if database corruption is encountered, or if an attempt is made to open a file that is not an SQLite database, the default behaviour is to delete the file and create an empty database file in its place. In a SEE-enabled build, the default behaviour is to throw an exception.`

Comment: @Aegis I needed custom SQL functions to calculate distance and order by this distance

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to store that distance value in the record itself you could calculate it when you insert the data in DB? or is this distance calculated between different Rows? This would eliminate the whole need for SQLite Android Bindings and also reduce the apk size and probably also the compile time. And it would also be a performance gain for the app itself.

Comment: @Aegis It uses the users current location and has to calculate the distance between that and the stored values so the database has to calculate the distance

Comment: Well the template @Rüdiger looks good if you remove the static getInstance and volatile sInstance. Then if you use a ContentProvider to do all the CRUD operations don't have to worry about more instances trying to read or write data to the db from to meany places.

Comment: Also did you check with a debugger when running through the code before you get that exception if the database file exist? Cause it could be some synchronization error when opening or creating the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this template

```
public class MyDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDatabase.db";
    private static final int SCHEMA = 1;
    private static volatile MyDBHelper sInstance;


    private MyDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA);
    }

    public static MyDBHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            synchronized (MyDBHelper.class) {
                if (sInstance == null) {
                    sInstance = new MyDBHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
                }
            }
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // create your tables here
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // handle db upgrade or leave blank
    }
}
```